# why does "make" delete target files only if implicit

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have a Makefile like this

```
B1.txt: A1.txt
    python big_long_program.py A1.txt > $@

correct1.txt: B1.txt reference.txt
    diff -q B1.txt reference.txt
    touch $@
```

Then the output when I make correct1.txt is pretty well what I would expect:

```
python big_long_program.py A1.txt > B1.txt
diff -q B1.txt reference.txt
touch correct1.txt
```

Now if I have lots of files, B1.txt, B2.txt, B3.txt etc, so create an implicit rule:

```
B%.txt: A%.txt
    python big_long_program.py A$*.txt > $@

correct%.txt: B%.txt reference.txt
    diff -q B$*.txt reference.txt
    touch $@
```

Instead this happens when I make correct1.txt:

```
python big_long_program.py A1.txt > B1.txt
diff -q B1.txt reference.txt
touch correct1.txt
rm B1.txt
```

i.e. there difference is that now the file B1.txt has been deleted, which in many cases is really bad.

So why are implicit rules different? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The behavior you observe and analyze is documented in [10.4 Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules). It states that intermediate files are indeed treated differently.

> The second difference is that if make does create b in order to update
>   something else, it deletes b later on after it is no longer needed.
>   Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make also
>   does not exist after make. `make` reports the deletion to you by
>   printing a `rm -f` command showing which file it is deleting.

The documentation does not explicitly explain *why* it behaves like this. Looking in the file [ChangeLog.1](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/ChangeLog.1#n4824), there is a reference to the `remove_intermediates` function as far back as 1988. At that time, disk space was expensive and at a premium.

If you do not want this behavior, mention the targets you want to keep somewhere in the makefile as an explicit prerequisite or target or use [the `.PRECIOUS` or the `.SECONDARY` special built-in targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets) for that.

With thanks to [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) for the additional comments, see below.

Comment: You don't have to use `.PRECIOUS` or `.SECONDARY`.  All you have to do is mention the targets you want to keep somewhere in the makefile as an explicit prerequisite or target.  So for example, you can say `alltxt: B1.txt B2.txt B3.txt` etc.

Comment: @MadScientist You are right of course, there are multiple options to avoid this deletion. Since you mentioned this other option, would there be a reason for you to prefer one mechanism over the other?

Comment: Personally I always prefer any "normal" make behavior over to any "special" targets.  `.PRECIOUS` has other effects which you may not want.  It's often the case, if you think about it, that _if_ these files are really needed for some reason, that it's handy to have them as a prerequisite of some target somewhere, anyway.

Comment: @MadScientist That makes sense. I have updated my answer, thanks for helping me to improve it.

Comment: As for why this happens, it is historical from back when disk space was expensive and at a premium.  It was mainly intended to be used with static libraries, where you can update the library by replacing individual object files rather than rebuilding it from scratch.  Since you don't need all the other .o's, only the out-of-date ones, you can delete them and save disk space without increasing build times.

Comment: That seems like a poor design decision to me - if the file is intermediate and can be deleted, why not make it all one rule? Perhaps the real answer is I am using "make" for things it was never intended for.

Comment: Because you'd have to have more rules.  Instead of one rule that build objects and one rule that adds them into libraries, you'd have to have one rule that builds objects, one that adds existing objects into a library, and a third that both builds objects and adds them into libraries at the same time.  And I don't think you can use both the latter rules at the same time: how does make decide which one to use?  You might want to preserve some objects but not others.  The current behavior is capability at the expense of complexity.